# my website takes time to load how to reduce it?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database

I have developed my website with asp.net and c# with MySql as back end. But even after optimizing css, Javascript and Images still takes time to load my website [www.cloudionpro.com](http://cloudionpro.com/).

Please help do I need to change something in my coding or its a mysql server issue?

Comment: Use your browser's Web Inspector to look at the timing chart.

Answer (score 0):

I loaded your site in Chrome and is reported the HTML of the page itself loaded in 93ms, of which 51ms was spent waiting for the HTML to be generated. 51ms is acceptable, but probably could be improved: it's likely you're making a lot of MySQL database calls that could be optimized (by paralleising them, or executing a query-batch).

Chrome reports the Google Maps API you're using failed to load, caused by scripting errors, which is also causing problems, open your browser's console for details of those. It looks like your site has a dependency on jQuery but your site never loads it.